# Type Difference when using Exchange Management Shell and Remote PSSession

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

When managing a remote Exchange 2010 server, I establish a new PSSession as documented by Microsoft.  I then run:

```
$group = Get-DistributionGroup "A Group"
$group.ManagedBy | Get-Member
```

Which returns:

```
TypeName: System.String
```

However, when running the exact same commands on an Exchange server itself (via Remote Desktop), I get:

```
TypeName: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId
```

This (ADObjectId) is the data structure I want (along with all the methods I want to use).

How do I get this data structure in my Remote Exchange Powershell session?  I need to manipulate it and not just see the contents.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the Exchange Management Tools installed on the computer you're running the remote Powershell session from?

Comment: No.  I have a PSSession remotely to Exchange.  It is the accepted way of administration http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2015/01/28/directly-loading-exchange-2010-or-2013-snapin-is-not-supported.aspx

Comment: I used the Exchange Management Shell from a non-Exchange server and received `TypeName: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId`. Not sure if that is the only solution, but it may be an option. I let EMS establish and configure the remote session.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the Exchange management tools installed on the local machine to get it rendered as that object type.  Objects returned from remote sessions are serialized to clixml by the remote session, and then de-serialized at the local session when they are received.  Serialization will remove all object methods, and may result in loss of fidelity in complex objects.